# Flat embedded surfaces in arbitrary 3-manifolds.

Tags: riemann-surfaces

It is generically known that any surface (at least embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ - and see edit below) can be deformed so that it is flat - i.e. has a metric of zero curvature - as long as one adds some conical singularities (for reference, here's an overview by Zorich ([link](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609392)) with the main results I am referring to being Troyanov ([link](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-324-02/S0002-9947-1991-1005085-9/home.html))).

My question is would this still be true for a surface embedded in an arbitrary 3-manifold? The Zorich paper is unclear, and the Troyanov results seem to be for a Riemann surface without explicit embedding. It seems a bit too much to hope for, but the basic technique is by solving some differential equations, which are local. Anyone know anything about this?

EDIT: It's not true that "any surface" can be flattened in this matter - there are some conditions, which vary depending on which result we are looking at. For instance, genus $g>1$ is a classic result, although in that Troyanov paper he proves the following must be true:
$$2\pi\chi(S)+\sum(\theta_i-2\pi)<0$$
for a set of singular points $p_i$ with angles $\theta_i$.

Comment: Dear levitopher, I don't have an answer to your question, but here is an example you might be able to visualize, and see what conclusions you come to: consider $S^2 \times S^1$, which you can visualize as a spherical shell $S^2 \times [0,1]$ with the outer and inner boundary identified, and take the surface to the be any of the spheres $S^2 \times \{t\}$ for some $t \in [0,1]$.  It's not immediately obvious to me that there is room to flatten this sphere in $S^2 \times S^1$, since it is "wrapped around" in a non-trivial way.  Regards,

Comment: What's a zero curvature embedding of $S^2$?   Isn't the Troyanov theorem only for surfaces of genus $2$ or larger?

Comment: There are a variety of results (including one for $g>1$) but the specific condition I am referring to is $2\pi\chi (S)+\sum (\theta_i-2\pi)<0$ for a set of singularities with angles $\theta_i$. In any case, your statement about the spheres is certainly helpful.

Comment: But even with those conditions satisfied, there isn't an embedding of the sphere in $\mathbb R^3$, is there?  I'm not seeing one.

Comment: I see - I've added an edit for some clarification.